# How I can add attachments to a docusign email using the sdk?

Tags: docusignapi

It is possible to send document attachments by email, when send a document to sign? I need to attach additional documents that do not required a signature.

Thanks,
EV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SDK/API to add documents to an envelope, even if they do not require signature. You can even add attachment tabs via the API so that signers can add their own attachments. You cannot, as far as I know, add attachments to email messages generated by the DocuSign system.

Answer (score 0):

Inbar is correct. In addition, you could send your own emails to signers (in any format you like), and include a link to the signing ceremony via your app.

See this [article](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/long-lived-embedded-signing-urls) for more.